# Thousand comma separator issue only last 3 digit is validating

Tags: javascript, html

I try  to convert the number in text box as comma separated values while typing but only the last values are taken.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   function addCommas(nStr) {
        nStr += '';
        x = nStr.split('.');
        x1 = x[0];
        x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
        var rgx = /(^\d{2})|(\d{1,3})(?=\d{1,3}|$)/g;
        while (rgx.test(x1)) {
            x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
        }
        return x1 + x2;
   }


</script>
```

This is the HTML file:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtbudamt" runat="server" CssClass="text_box" Height="22px" Width="140px" onkeyup="this.value=addCommas(this.value);"    onkeydown="return (event.keyCode!=13);" AutoComplete="Off" TabIndex="7"></asp:TextBox>
```

- When I enter numbers till 9999 it gives correct output like 9,999
- When I go for 10000 it gives 1,0,000

Comment: The more appropriate way to add comma would be to parse number as `int` and format the value using your culture.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print a number with commas as thousands separators in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-a-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript)

Comment: i cant do that because i have to perform some math function also the external api will take only int or double , and more over i just what the comma separator in the html page alone

Comment: @ivar i did check with the link you have attached but , none of them are working for exception this jquery and with this mistake

Comment: @dr.engg You checked all 53 answers already? Simply use `return parseFloat(nStr).toLocaleString();`. (Also, there is no jQuery what so ever in the code you provided.)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use [toLocaleString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) for this. It is also supported on most browsers.

```js
function addCommas(nStr) {
   return parseFloat(nStr).toLocaleString('en-GB');
}
```

Comment: this method is not allowing me to go beyond 9999 like if i type 10000 it auto changes to 1 and becomes NaN